# material-ui Drawer listitem show active item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show the selected item highlighted in my drawer. Following is my code

```
  <Link to ="/#" style={{textDecoration:'none'}}>
  <ListItem button selected={selectedIndex === 0} onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)} >
    <ListItemIcon>
      <HomeIcon  color="secondary"/>
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Home" />
  </ListItem>
  </Link>
  <Link to ="/movies" style={{textDecoration:'none'}}>
  <ListItem button selected={selectedIndex === 1} onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 1)}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <MovieFilterIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Movies" />
  </ListItem>
  </Link>
```

following are the functions I call for the drawer

```
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(1);

  const handleListItemClick = (event, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };
```

**What I want is when I click on the movies it should go to movies & movies list item should show as active.**
I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're likely facing is `selectedIndex` resetting to its default state (in your case, 1) when the new page is navigated to.

The simplest fix is to add a useEffect function to set the correct value for `selectedIndex` when the client mounts. Switch over the browser's URL to determine which value to set:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    switch (window.location.pathname) {
      case "/":
        setSelectedIndex(0)
        break
      case "/movies":
        setSelectedIndex(1)
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }, [])
```

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-active-drawer-demo-mvvtn?file=/src/components/navbar.js:1434-1739) with a setup similar to yours so you can see everything in detail